# Using curl to retrieve data from Apex: Where to get security token?

Tags: apex, webservices, oauth2, apexrest

```
curl -v https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=<your_consumer_key>" -d "client_secret=<your_consumer_secret>" -d "username=<your_username>" -d "password=<your_password_and_security_token>" -H 'X-PrettyPrint:1'
```

I'm using this to enable OAUTH2 on Salesforce using CURL (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices) but it seems it's not even specified where to get the security token. Can anyone help me where to find it? I tried connecting without the security token but it generates an `authentication failure` error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found it, I checked my email since Salesforce sends it whenever I change my password. Other alternatives include Resetting the Security Token on My Settings (when using Salesforce Classic), not sure how to do this in Lightning though.